# how to remove all models through a plugin?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have read the gazebo source code,and I find the function "gazebo::physics::World::Clear()" not implemented.So,how can I remove all models through a plugin?Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4737/how-to-remove-all-models-through-a-plugin?/) by [bruce](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/527/bruce/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks for pointing out the lack of World::Clear.

Here is a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/785) that fixes the problem.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1